# Why does requresive least squares need to have a variance onto the input signal?

Tags: systems-of-equations, dynamical-systems, control-theory, linear-control, system-identification

Requresive Least Squares(RLS) is a famous algorithm for solving linear system and it's used a lot with system identification for finding parameters for a polynomial function:

$$yA(q) = uB(q) + eC(q)$$

Where $y$ is the output signal, $u$ is the input signal and $e$ is the noise. In RLS-case, we can assume that $e$ is the model error.

The only problem is that $u$ need to varying over time, else, $A(q)$ will be unstable. Why does $u$ not to varying over time. Why can't $u$ be a fixed value?

Comment: I assume you are referring to the persistence of excitation condition?

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen Yes! Excitation. I have a book that says excitation is needed because else the model will become unstable. I have tested RLS in both MATLAB and C code and it will give the same model(100%) if the input signal have excitation condition. But if the input signal have no excitation, then the C code and the MATLAB code will perform differently. Most of the case - unstable model. I'm building a adaptive controller. The code is free.

Comment: My answer to another question might help: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1072232/111671

Comment: @obareey So there is nothing I can do about this? Just accept it and use a input signal that varying over time?

Comment: Yes, with fixed $u$ you can only identify first-order systems.

Comment: @obareey are you sure about that ? I did sysid with recursive least square where I curvefit onto a first order model (ARMAX) where u = 100 and y = 20 + random noise. It gave an unstable model. The algorithm is avaiable at Mataveid. My sysid library.